# Can I copy a directory from a server to my computer?

Tags: linux, ssh

Im trying to copy a directory from my server to my computer?

How would I do this using ssh. This is the directory I would like to copy :

```
/var/www/vhosts/123.co.uk/httpdocs
```

I would like to copy the entire directory for 123.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`scp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy):

```
$ scp -r 123.co.uk:/var/www/vhosts/123.co.uk/httpdocs localdir
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` to copy directories between systems.  This will use the ssh protocol.

```
$ rsync -axh remotehost:/var/www/vhosts/123.co.uk/httpdocs/ httpdocs/
```

This will copy the `httpdocs` directory from the remote host to a local directory called `httpdocs`.  The slashes on the end of the directories are important.  The `-a` option means to copy in archive mode, preserving ownership and permissions when possible.  The `-x` option means to stay on one filesystem.  The `-h` option means to display numbers in human readable form.

You may also add the `-u` option if the target folder already exists and you want to only transfer what differs (this is the main power of `rsync`).  You can use `-v` option for more verbosity.  You can also use `rsync` to do recursive copies from local to local or from one remote system to another remote system.

Once you have `rsync` in your tool belt, you will never want to use `cp` or `scp` again for recursive copies.

On older systems, you may have to add the `-e ssh` option.  See the man page for more information.